# matplotlib: 3 channel binary RGB image only shows black

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, imshow

I have three 2D datasets that I'm trying to plot as an RGB image using `matplotlib`.  I thought this would be quite straightforward but I'm finding it very frustrating.

Here's the bit of code I'm currently using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_rgb import RGBAxes

b = simg["B"].astype(bool).astype(int)
g = simg["G"].astype(bool).astype(int)
r = simg["R"].astype(bool).astype(int)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = RGBAxes(fig, [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], pad=0.0)
ax.imshow_rgb(r, g, b, interpolation="none")
```

where `simg` is the dictionary with my single channel images in it, stored as `(n, m)` arrays with `dtype = uint16`.  The original data is "almost binary", so I'm using the `astype`s to threshold it.  For reference, each channel contains about 5-10% 1s after thresholding.  This is working as intended so I don't think it's the problem, but I tried removing the `astype`s anyway and it doesn't fix the issue.

Here's the result of the above snippet:

[image: nothing but black]

In that screenshot I've zoomed way in, and the area I marqueed off should be a green pixel.  This data is present in the image, as rolling the mouse over this pixel shows that it indeed has a value of `[0, 1, 0]` in the tkinter window.

I thought this might have something to do with the `RGBAxes`, so I tried a much simpler method of displaying this data:

```
rgb = np.dstack((r, g, b))
plt.imshow(rgb, interpolation="none")
```

This creates an `(n, m, 3)` array, which the `imshow` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) says will be interpreted as an RGB image, but this also just plots a completely black image.  I also tried all of the different available interpolation methods, and tried changing the plotting backend (currently `tkinter`, but I also tried `Qt5`).

The data plots just fine if I only plot one channel.  For example:

```
plt.imshow(b, cmap="binary_r", interpolation="none")
```

results in the image:

[image: working binary blue channel]

which is exactly what I expect to see in that channel.  So something about trying to plot the three channels at once is not working the way I expect it to.

I'd appreciate any guidance anyone can give here, and I'm happy to provide any additional information I can that might help.  If I can't get this working I'll probably just try rolling my own solution using `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable` and manually combining the RGB channels, but if I go that route I'll also need to re-implement the features of `RGBAxes` (i.e. the separate, smaller R, G, and B plots beside the combined RGB image) which would be kind of tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem.  As is almost always the case, it was the part that I was confident was not the problem that was, in fact, the problem.

Having a more careful look at the `imshow` documentation (linked in the question) reveals that `imshow` interprets `(n, m, 3)` arrays in two different ways depending on their data type.  For arrays of floats, the data is assumed to be in the range `[0.0, 1.0]`, but for integers the data is assumed to be in the range `[0, 255]`.  So essentially it *was* plotting correctly, but because my data was integer data (both before thresholding using `astype` and after), I was essentially plotting colors as close to black as possible in 8-bit RGB without them actually *being* black.  My monitor is not that great, and they were all indistinguishable from black for me.

The easy solution is to simply change the type of the data to a float instead of an int after thresholding:

```
b = simg["B"].astype(bool).astype(float)
g = simg["G"].astype(bool).astype(float)
r = simg["R"].astype(bool).astype(float)
```

and this now results in an excellent three-channel RGB image as expected:
[image: working now]